# fatal error: uncaught error: cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo este problema a la hora de llamar a la función para volcar los datos que quiero.

He creado una función para listar unos items según su id:

```
function list_item_by_id_controller(){
    global $link, $gf_query;

    $id_types = array('eid','hid','pid','poid','bid');

    $getKeys = array_keys($_GET);

    foreach ( $getKeys as $k ){
        if( in_array($k, $id_types) ){
            $id = $_GET[$k]; 
        }
    }

    if(!$id){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i101';
            return false;
    }

    $query = list_item_by_id($id);

    if( !$query ){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i102';
        return false;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Cuando llamo a la función en la pág donde quiero imprimir los datos me sale el siguiente error:

```
fatal error: uncaught error: cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in c:\mamp\htdocs\gourfood_02-08__modificado\public_html\templates\product-single.php:8 stack trace: #0 c:\mamp\htdocs\gourfood_02-08__modificado\public_html\single.php(23): include() #1 {main} thrown in c:\mamp\htdocs\gourfood_02-08__modificado\public_html\templates\product-single.php on line 8
```

En la línea 8 de `product-single.php` tengo la siguiente línea de código `<h2 class="title"> <?php echo $i['item'] ?></h2>`

He probado cambiando en el modelo  `mysqli_num_rows` por `mysqli_fetch_array` por si fuera ese el problema pero nada.

Este es el modelo

```
function list_item_by_id($id){
  global $link;

  $id = (int)$id;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM items
          INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias_id = categorias.id
          WHERE items.id = $id";

  $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  if( $num_rows > 0 ){
    return $query;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Alguien sabría decirme que me falla? Gracias

EDITO: el código al rededor de `echo $i['item]` es el siguiente:
En la página single.php

```
<?php 
require('load.php');

require('templates/header.php');
require('templates/navbar.php');

$i = list_item_by_id_controller();

?>
    <div class="single-main">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php#carta">Carta</a></li>
            <li class="active">Producto</li>
          </ol>

          <?php if($i): ?>
            <?php include('templates/product-single.php') ?>
          <?php else: ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p>Oooppps, parece que ha habido un error. Si lo deseas, puedes volver a la portada pinchando <a href="index.php"> aquí</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Luego en `product-single.php` es donde incluyo los `echos` para volcar los datos:

```
<article class="product-single">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="images/03-small.jpg" class="img-responsive portfolio-img" alt="Project Title">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="product-detail">
            <h2 class="title"> <?php echo $i['item'] ?></h2>
            <h4 class="price"><?php echo $i['precio'] ?> €</h4>
            <p class="descripcion"><?php echo $i['descripcion'] ?></p>

            <form method="POST" id="orderForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" value="1">
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Deberías indicar el código al rededor de `echo $i['item']`

Comment: Veamos, si tú quieres mostrar datos de al menos una columna de la consulta del `SELECT` es evidente que debes devolver un array con esos datos, y no el número de filas encontradas. Ese aspecto no queda claro en la pregunta. Luego, es necesario que muestres el código donde intentas leer o mostrar los datos, o sea el código que incluye la famosa línea 8.

Comment: @Cedano ya he editado mi pregunta para tener más datos. Muchas gracias por tu interés

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Te lo dice el error**. Intentas usar como una array un objeto. Es bueno comprobar si una variable que se espera que sea un array es realmente un array.

Pudes hacer usar **var_dump()** sobre el objeto que esta generandote el error para ver si tiene datos y como sacarlos para lo que necesitas.

Luego tienes algunas cosas que son propensas a generte errores. La función **list_item_by_id_controller()** opera sobre **$_GET** directamente, esperas que contenga un array, aunque puede tener cualquier cosa... se puede reescribir su contenido en cualquier punto del programa, yo le pasaría el array como argumento a la función o usaría una *clausula de salvaguarda* recuperando todo su contenido...

```
function list_item_by_id_controller(){
    global $link, $gf_query;

    $arr = $_GET;
    if ( ! is_array( $arr )) {

        //Código que te indique que no tienes lo esperado

        return;
    }

    $id_types = array('eid','hid','pid','poid','bid');


    $getKeys = array_keys( $arr );

    foreach ( $getKeys as $k ){
        if( in_array($k, $id_types) ){
            $id = $arr[ $k ]; 
        }
    }

    //Resto de código...
```

Usar globales tampoco me gusta nada...

Luego en la misma función, la variable **$id** la estas asignando dentro de un *condicional*, dentro de un *foreach*, ¿y si nunca se le asigna un valor? La usas más abajo, deberías inicializarla a NULL, antes del foreach.

No seguí mirando código, tengo cosas que hacer ahora.

Un saludo.

Comment: este es el `var_dump()` del objeto: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Ok, creo que te indica que has recuperado una fila. Puedes extraer un objeto con los datos con: *mysqli_result::fetch_object* o el array con *mysqli_result::fetch_array* y haz un *var_dump* del resultado. Puedes ver la documentación de ambos métodos en:

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php - 

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: Gracias @Orici me has ayudado a solucionar el problema, ya me vuelca los datos

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos.
Un saludo.